# Pyinstaller error: Unrecognized arguments when passing a spec file

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I run `pyi-makespec --onefile MyScript.py`.
After this I add `a.datas += Tree('./MyData', prefix='.')`
to the generated spec file. Then i tried to run:

```
pyinstaller MyScript.py --onefile MyScript.spec
```

but Pyinstaller returns with:

```
pyinstaller-script.py: error: unrecognized arguments: MyScript.spec
```

I'm using PyInstaller 3.3.1 and Python 3.6.5.

Have anyone an idea why it didn't let me pass the spec file?

Answer (score 0):

The option `--onefile` does not support arguments, if you changed generated spec file, you have to pass it to the pyinstaller, how documentation [outlines](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#using-spec-files):

> After you have created a spec file and modified it as necessary, you
> build the application by passing the spec file to the pyinstaller
> command.

So the right way to call the command would be:

```
pyinstaller --onefile MyScript.spec
```